# Beta Site Stats Broken

Tags: support, beta-phase, site-stats

[image: Site Stats Broken]

I've seen this in IE 8 and Firefox 4.  This does not seem to affect all sites, though.  Security and Mechanics are affected, but RPG is not.  I'll check around other sites and update this question as I find more.

Affected:

- [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)
- [Mechanics](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/)
- [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)
- [Sci-Fi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)
- [Sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)
- [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Unaffected:

- [RPG](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)
- [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/)
- [Music](https://music.stackexchange.com/)
- [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/)
- [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/)
- [Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/)
- [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/)
- [Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/)
- [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)
- [Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/)
- [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)
- [Homebrewing](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/)

Upon further review, this seems to be a sporadic problem - coming and going somewhat unpredictably.  "Affected" now lists the sites I *have* seen it on, but the problem may not currently exist.  Some of these were previously "Unaffected" though.

Although the Site Stats image says "loading", the statistics do not appear within an expected reasonable amount of time (if at all).

I just did a re-check of all the above sites, and it seems the issue is cleared up for now.  Any ideas as to what might have caused this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the problem *is*?

Comment: @John - I thought that what I put in the screenshot *was* the problem?

Comment: FWIW, I did go on SharePoint not long after you posted this question and only got the *loading* bit of the stats. It does seem OK now though.

Comment: Ah.  The last machine I was on blocks imgur so I can't see screenshots.  I see the problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug -- the stats panel is heavily cached and sometimes there can be intermittent errors populating it on builds and so forth.

Every site you listed is fine now.

When it says "loading..." I would take that at face value unless the loading goes on for more than a few hours.